# ASP.NET Web site spawing hundereds of Connections to SQL Server Express instance - how can I identify culprit code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-6

This is a quite a big, quite a badly coded ASP.NET website that I am currently tasked with maintaining. One issue that I'm not sure how to solve is that at seemingly random times, the live web site will lock up completely, page access is ok, but anything that touches the database causes the application to hang indefinitely.

The cause seems to be many more open connections to the database than you would expect of a lowish level traffic web site. Activity monitor shows 150+ open connections, most with an Application value of '.NET SqlClient Data Provider', with the network service login.

A quick solution is to restart the SQL Server service (I've recycled the ASP.NET app pool also just to ensure that the application lets go of anything, and stops any code from reattempting to open connections if there was some sort of loop process that I'm unaware of). This doesn't however help me solve the problem.

The application uses a Microsoft SQLHelper class, which is a pretty common library, so I'm fairly confident that the code that uses this class will have connections closed where required.

I have however spotted a few DataReaders that are not closed properly. I think I'm right in saying that a DataReader can keep the underlying connection open even if that connection is closed because it is a connected class (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Something that it perculiar is that one of the admins restarted the server (not the database server, the actual server) and immediatley, the site would hang again. The culprit was again 150+ open database connections.

Does anybody have any diagnostic technique that they can share with me for working out where this is happening?

**Update:** SQL Server Log files show many entries like this (30+)

2010-10-15 13:28:53.15 spid54      Starting up database 'test_db'.

I'm wondering if the server is getting hit by an attacker. That would explain the many connections right after boot, and at seemingly random times.

**Update:** Have changed the AutoClose property, though still hunting for a solution!

**Update 2:** See my answer to this question for the solution!

Comment: I feel so, so, so sorry for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue came up again today and I managed to solve it quite easility, so I thought I'd post back here.

In this case, you can assume that the connection spamming is coming from the same code block, so to find the code block, I opened activity monitor and checked the details for some of the many open connections (Right click > details).

This showed me the offending SQL, which you can search for in your application code / stored procedures.

Once I'd found it, it was as I suspected, an unclosed data reader. Problem is now solved.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Lots and lots of `Starting up database`: Set the `AutoClose` property to `false` : **[REF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/610eb524-eed8-448a-99ad-4262ab4276bd)**

---

You are correct about your DataReaders: make sure you close them. However, I have experienced many problems with connections spawning out of control even when connections were closed properly. Connection pooling didn't seem to be working as expected since each post-back created a new SqlConnection. To avoid this seemingly uneeded re-creation of the connection,  adopted a Singleton approach to my DAL. So I create a single DataAdapter and send all my data requests through it. Although I've been told that this is unwise, I have not received any support for that claim (and am still eager to read any documentation/opinion to this effect: I want to get better, not be status quo). I have a DataAdapter class for you to consider if you like.

If you are in SQL 2005+, you should be able to use Activity Monitor to see the "Details" of each connection which sometimes gives you the last statement executed. Perhaps this will help you track the statement back to some place in code.

Comment: Ok, that's a good tip on the AutoClose. Read up some more here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/autocloseandautoshrinkjustdont/984/. Don't think it's my main issue though.

Comment: @Bomb, I would say not, but it is the likely culprit for your question updated.

Comment: With regard to your singleton approach to DB access, I think other devs will suggest that it's a bad idea as it creates a bottle neck in your application. Unless the singleton had some kind of thread pooling involved, it would have forced all db access to work in serial, which could have caused the app to hang for User A if User B's request involved a long running query.

Comment: sorry didn't mean to dismiss it. I agree, it is certainly the culprit for my update.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend downloading http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/ to see what queries are happening, and sort of work backwards from there. Good luck man!

Answer (score 0):

Many types such as `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` and their derived types (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlReader`) implement the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface/pattern.

Without re-gurgitating what has [already](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) [been](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx) [written](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/02/03/looking-at-.net-the-disposable-pattern.aspx) on the [subject](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/501/idisposable-pattern/) you can take advantage of this mechanism via the `using` statement.

As a rule of thumb you should always try to wrap your DbConnection, DbCommand and DbDataReader objects with the `using` statement which will generate MSIL to call `IDisposable`'s `Dispose` method. Usually in the `Dispose` method there is code to clean up unmanaged resources such as closing database connections.

For example:

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", cn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cn.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while(rdr.Read())
      { 
        ... do stuff etc 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will ensure that the `Dispose` methods are called on all of the objects used immediately after use. For example the `Dispose` methods of the `SqlConnection` closes the underlying database connection right away instead of leaving it around for the next garbage collection run.

Little changes like this improve your applications ability to scale under heavy load. As you already know, "Acquire expensive resources late and release early". The `using` statement is a nice bit of syntactic sugar to help you out.

If you're using VB.NET 2.0 or later it has the same construct:

> [Using Statement (Visual Basic) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)
>   [using Statement (C# Reference) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the post. The code's not really the problem, I'm pretty up to speed. This project has a lot of code already though, and I really just need to find which bit is the culprit - it's diagnostics I need here.

Comment: @bombdefused - no problem, just thought it might help. It's sometimes hard to gauge another users level of expertise.